# creating a matrix of counts from large vector of numbers

Tags: r, matrix

Imagine I have a very large set of X,Y numbers between 0 and 1 (ignore third column for now):

```
0.5 0.1 1.88093e-296
0.500559    0.100946    1.14878e-296
0.500708    0.100903    1.00751e-296
0.500708    0.100903    1.00751e-296
0.498227    0.100267    8.935e-296
0.488925    0.0997211   2.70318e-292
0.484398    0.100495    1.19442e-290
0.476617    0.10003 7.06571e-288
0.474858    0.0993702   2.95419e-287
0.470889    0.0990931   7.00569e-286
```

I seek to create a matrix of counts of how many X,Y occur within a certain value bracket. For example, how many data points occurred where

```
0.49<X<0.5 and 0.49<Y<0.5
```

To do this, I want a 2D matrix with the count of number of X,Y within that bracket. I wrote the following:

```
data <- read.table(args[1]);

sizeuse<-100;

mdat <- matrix(rep(0,sizeuse*sizeuse), nrow = sizeuse, ncol = sizeuse)
nr<-nrow(data);

for(i in 1:nr){#1:1000) {
  x<-floor(data[i,]$V1/(1/sizeuse));
  y<-floor(data[i,]$V2/(1/sizeuse));

  mdat[ x , y  ] <- mdat[ x  , y  ]+1;
}
```

Sizeuse is the size of number of brackets between 0 and 1. The problem is that this code takes forever, I wrote the same algorithm in C++ and it runs in 2 seconds. What am I missing ?

Comment: check out the `cut` and `table` functions

Answer (score 1):

So with the sample data

```
dd<- data.frame(
    X = c(0.5, 0.500559, 0.500708, 0.500708, 0.498227, 
        0.488925, 0.484398, 0.476617, 0.474858, 0.470889),
    Y = c(0.1, 
        0.100946, 0.100903, 0.100903, 0.100267, 0.0997211, 0.100495, 
        0.10003, 0.0993702, 0.0990931),
    OTHER = c(1.88093e-296, 1.14878e-296, 
        1.00751e-296, 1.00751e-296, 8.935e-296, 2.70318e-292, 1.19442e-290, 
        7.06571e-288, 2.95419e-287, 7.00569e-286)
)
```

I would use

```
xc<-cut(dd$X, breaks=(46:51)/100)
yc<-cut(dd$Y, breaks=(9:11)/100)

table(xc,yc)
```

These breaks cover the range of the sample table, but if you want a 100x100 matrix, you can change them both to `breaks=(0:100)/100`. Make sure the intervals of `cut` have the right open/closed sides that you want. You can always check to make sure all values are in the table by running `sum( table(xc,yc) ) == nrow(dd)`